# rest_authentication_invalid_api_key_secret JWT wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, jwt, wp-api

i used https://github.com/WP-API/jwt-auth for authentication

I created `api-key` and `api-secret` in profile page

when i call api (http://acms-srs.localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/token), showing errors

```
{
    "code": "rest_authentication_invalid_api_key_secret",
    "message": "The API key-pair is invalid.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I ended up having to create a new user with the same role, then the api/secret I generated for that user worked.